# Class implementing ServletContextListener (AppContextListener) is not found when deploy on wildfly server

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, servletcontextlistener, wildfly-12

I have a dynamic web project Java and I am trying to deploy it on wildfly server. An error below shows that the server can't find the AppContextListener class which implements ServletContextListener.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Prj.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Prj.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Prj.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:151)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1714)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1693)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1540)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.code.ui.config.AppContextListener from [Module "deployment.Prj.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsComponentDeployer.deploy(JaxrsComponentDeployer.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.code.ui.config.AppContextListener from [Module "deployment.Prj.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:199)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsComponentDeployer.deploy(JaxrsComponentDeployer.java:87)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Is that class in the `Prj.war/WEB-INF/classes`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Yes it is but I have found the problem in some missing dependencies required for wildfly server, when I clean and refresh the project the missing dependencies appear instead of this unknown error.